# Pyinstaller and django Failed to colelct submodules

Tags: django, pyinstaller

Here is my command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --log-level "ERROR" --hidden-import "rest_framework.schemas" --hidden-import "django.contrib.gis.utils" --paths "C:/Users/a/Documents/GitHub/compute-local/backend/.env/Lib/site-packages" --additional-hooks-dir "C:/Users/a/Documents/GitHub/compute-local/backend/extra-hook" --hidden-import "djoser.urls" --paths "C:/Users/a/Documents/GitHub/compute-local/backend/.env/Lib/site-packages/djoser/urls" --paths "C:/Users/a/Documents/GitHub/compute-local/backend/.env/Lib/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas" --hidden-import "djoser" --hidden-import "rest_framework"  "C:/Users/a/Documents/GitHub/compute-local/backend/manage.py"
```

And here are the errors

> WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'djoser.urls' because
> importing 'djoser.urls' raised:
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
> REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either
> define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings. 763 WARNING: Failed to
> collect submodules for 'rest_framework.schemas' because importing
> 'rest_framework.schemas' raised:
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
> REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either
> define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Can someone help me navigate this issue?

Comment: whitch version of python you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically copied the Python libraries from the .env file into the PyInstaller on the same level as the other libraries there and it worked.

I also copied the python DLLs into the folder.

Answer (score 0):

despite being just **warnings** not **errors**  the program is not running because of it . just use   [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)  A `.py` to `.exe` converter using a simple graphical interface and `PyInstaller` in Python.